# getting error at spring-hibernate-maven project

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, annotations

I am getting "class file functionContext not found" error when I try to run project. It was running without errors but after i write some unit tests and delete them It started to give this error. Here is the error stack trace;

### COMPILATION ERROR :

```
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:


An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jaxen.FunctionContext not found
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:554)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jaxen.FunctionContext not found
```

Comment: Can you check that you have jaxen in your dependency tree?

Answer (score 14):

Adding [jaxen](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen) to your libraries fixes this problem.

If you disable annotation processing in project properties, it will start working as well, but then you cannot use things like [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) (lombok generates getters/setters/hashcode/constructors on the fly).

Edit: Jaxen was hosted at codehouse, but codehouse is discontinued and jaxen.org is outdated. The link above points to maven repository, I am not sure if there is anything better.

[image: enable annotation processing]

Answer (score 8):

Are you useing Netbeans?

If so, go into the build settings for your project and unckeck "Enable Annotation Processing".

Regards

Comment: The problem with that is other annotations do not work either. So one cannot use lombok, for example.

Answer (score 6):

you need this dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems somehow the dependencies were not loading from net. So I selected 'Build with dependencies' and the build was successful...

Rgds,
Sup